# Does the kineticist Telekinetic Weapon work with bonuses and enhancement from any weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

Does the kineticist [Telekinetic Weapon](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/infusion-wild-talents#toc28) work with bonuses and enhancement from any weapon?

The ability mentions...

> When using a telekinetic blast with a magic weapon, **apply any enhancement bonuses and weapon qualities of the weapon to your blast *as if you had made a melee attack with that weapon.***

So does this limit the magical weapons types you can use cause of the **"as if you had made a melee attack with that weapon"**

Ex: +1 Spear Flame Burst, with TK Blast throw random unattended 5lb/Lv object deals TK Blast damage with +1 Enhancement and Fire Burst property of the weapon up 30 feet away? or Use TK Blast with Kinetic Blade, Fist or Whip since it says as if made with melee attack weapon and with in melee range?

Or can it be any magical weapon and in using it with TK Blast you just add the weapon's enhancement and properties?

Ex2: +1 Repeating Cross Bow of Undead Bane, with TK Blast means firing the weapon and adding TK Blast damage to bolt fired with +1 enhancement and Undead Bane.

Comment: is that a +1 Repeating Crossbow that you're [throwing at them](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/#Telekinetic_Blast)? Or are you trying to shoot-throw ammunition?

Answer (score 2):

Kineticist is, as always, a mess.

What the ability *tries* to say is that, when you use telekinetic blast to launch a magic weapon in place of the unattended object, the blast gets the enhancement bonuses and special qualities of said weapon.

This ability works not by holding on to your spear and telekinetically sending a random nearby object at your enemy. It works by using *that said spear* as the object.

Effectively, it is almost like as if you're throwing the weapon yourself, but instead of the regular throw weapon mechanics, you use the blast rules for the Kine.

Making it *extra clear*:

Using TK Blast doesn't add the magic properties of your weapon to a random object. It just lifts this other clause from the regular simple blast:

> Since the object is enfolded in strands of aether, even if you use
>   this power on a magic weapon or other unusual object, the attack
>   doesn’t use any of the magic weapon’s bonuses or effects.

Honestly, for 2 Burn, this ability is incredibly lame.

Comment: Thank you so much for making it very clear, this saves from picking it and I can tell a friend to avoid this for his Capt America build?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver If you want to make a Captain America build, you should pick Startoss Style, Startoss Comet and Startoss Shower, on a Brawler with the [Shield Champion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/archetypes/paizo-brawler-archetypes/shield-champion/) archetype. It is almost "ready to use" for that build.